# Regarding the regex in search module with and without raw text

Tags: python, regex, text

I am doing the following in python`2.7`

```
>>> a='hello team 123'
>>> b=re.search('hello team [0-9]+',a)
>>>
>>> b
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000022995E0>
>>> b=re.search(r'hello team [0-9]+',a)
>>> b
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002299578>
>>>
```

Now as you see, in one case i am doing the raw text while in the other it's without raw text.

From one of the posts on SO, i learnt:
The `r` means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored.

For an example:

'\n' will be treated as a newline character, while r'\n' will be treated as the characters \ followed by n

Then, why is my example working for both cases i.e with `r` and without `r`?
Is it because none of my example uses `\` ?

Also please look at the attached screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using any special characters in your string, so `r''` and `''` will do the same thing.

In `hello team [0-9]+` nothing needs to escaped. It will be passed to regex engine as it is. If you use special characters in your Python string then you need to escape them to pass them to regex engine.

There are two levels of escaping involved in regex. First level is Python string and second level regex engine.

So for example:

`'\\\\'` --> Python(string translation) ---> `'\\'` ---> Regex Engine(translation) ---> `'\'`

In order to avoid Python string translation you use raw strings.

`r'\\'` --> Python(string translation) ---> `'\\'` ---> Regex Engine(translation) ---> `'\'`

---

```
>>> print repr('\\')
'\\'
>>> print repr(r'\\')
'\\\\'
>>> print str('\\')
\
>>> print str(r'\\')
\\
```

Comment: when i do r'\\' i get '\\\\' BUT when i do  '\\' i get '\\'. As per what u said , is this behaviour expected? Please explain

Comment: I didn't understand how you are getting `'\\\\'` when you do `r'\\'`. Elaborate more. Start a new question if you will.

Comment: pardon my ignorance..i have edited my question..please have a look and confirm

Comment: @fsociety  when you don't use `print` statement `repr()` method is called internally and when you use print statement `str()` is called.